# How to use icons in material-ui v.1.3?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, google-material-icons

I'm confused about how to use icons in the current version of [material-ui](https://material-ui.com/style/icons/).

According to the [material-ui docs on icons](https://material-ui.com/style/icons/), under *SVG Material icons*:

> We provide a separate NPM package, [@material-ui/icons](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@material-ui/icons), that includes the 1,000+ official [Material icons](https://material.io/tools/icons/?style=baseline) converted to `SvgIcon` components.
>
> (...)
>
> You can use material.io/tools/icons to find a specific icon. When importing an icon, keep in mind that the names of the icons are PascalCase, for instance:
>
> - `delete` is exposed as `@material-ui/icons/Delete`
> - `delete forever` is exposed as `@material-ui/icons/DeleteForever`

An example they show is:

```
// Import icon
import DeleteIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Delete';

// ...

// Use icon in react somewhere
render() { return (
    <DeleteIcon />
)}
```

This works for many icons, but not for the **[file_copy](https://material.io/tools/icons/?icon=file_copy&style=baseline)**-icon.

However, I can get it work with:

```
<i className="material-icons">file_copy</i>
```

What is the expected approach to make this work?

I have, with `npm install --save`, installed `@material-ui/icons` *and* `material-design-icons`. (Initially only the first, but after not getting all icons to work I tried with the second too)

I have also included the `<link />`-tags from [material-ui installation guide](https://material-ui.com/getting-started/installation/)

However, I import with `import FileCopy from '@material-ui/icons/FileCopy';`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's fairly simple once you've installed an icon:

```
import IconName from '@material-ui/icons/{icon-name-here}';

<IconName/>
```

As you may have noticed there are quite a few icons missing from inside the `@material-ui/icons` folder, though if you navigate to the svg files on material.io you can choose to download the svg icon which you can use normally in the same convention or you can do what they do inside Material Icons package using `SvgIcon` and pasting the svg code taken from the `material.io` website.

```
<SvgIcon>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
    <circle cx="17" cy="4.54" r="2"/>
    <path d="M14 17h-2c0 1.65-1.35 3-3 3s-3-1.35-3-3 1.35-3 3-3v-2c-2.76 0-5 2.24-5 5s2.24 5 5 5 5-2.24 5-5zm3-3.5h-1.86l1.67-3.67C17.42 8.5 16.44 7 14.96 7h-5.2c-.81 0-1.54.47-1.87 1.2L7.22 10l1.92.53L9.79 9H12l-1.83 4.1c-.6 1.33.39 2.9 1.85 2.9H17v5h2v-5.5c0-1.1-.9-2-2-2z"/>
    <path fill="none" d="M0 0h24v24H0z"/>
</svg>
</SvgIcon>
```

This can then be exported as a component so it's reusable. The above would work for your copy Icon you wish to use.

Comment: Thank you both for good answers. I've accepted your answer because it's more general, and was also posted first.

Comment: I've pulled it into my create-react-app. And livereload speed took a massive hit. Any ideas how to mitigate this?

Answer (score 4):

You can discover the `material-ui` names of the icons by browsing `node_modules/@material-ui/icons`: sometimes they are slightly different than the ones on the Google material design site!

In this case, the file_copy icon from the Google site is named "ContentCopy" in material-ui:

```
 import ContentCopy from '@material-ui/icons/ContentCopy';
```

Comment: Thanks for the useful answer and specific solution to the single icon in question. I've decided to accept li x's answer because he was first and more general, but I appreciate the specificity in your answer. There can only be one accepted though.